# Как создать список моделей, чтобы присоединить к fit?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

Мне нужно вызывать несколько моделей, и решила попробовать их положить
в список, но скормить их потом не получается для обучения модели.
Может есть другой способ?

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder
func = ['LinearRegression()', 'DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=241)','KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5)',  'LogisticRegression()', 'GaussianNB()', 'SVC()']
def fit_predict_scaler(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, lr):
    lr = LabelEncoder().fit(lr).transform(lr)
    lr.fit(X_train, y_train)
    prediction = lr.predict(X_test)
    error = mean_absolute_error(prediction, y_test)
    return error
fit_predict_scaler(X_train, y_train, X_test, y_test, func[0])
ValueError: bad input shape ()
```

Comment: извините, но у вас какая-то каша... Что вы пытаетесь сделать? Куда вы хотите "скормить" модели?  PS кстати, вы создали список строк, а не список моделей

Comment: Как создать список моделей?

Comment: `func = [LinearRegression(), DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=241),KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5),  LogisticRegression(), GaussianNB(), SVC()]`

Comment: аaaaa - поробую

Comment: Только lr = LabelEncoder().fit(lr).transform(lr) убрать и норм.

Comment: # Victor VosMottor thanks Monica, может оформите как ответ?

Comment: @svil, похоже вы пытаетесь переизобрести [GridSearchCV](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.GridSearchCV.html)

Comment: чтобы обратиться к автору комметария надо поставить `at sign` перед его именем - @VictorVosMottorthanksMonica

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func = [LinearRegression(), DecisionTreeClassifier(random_state=241),KNeighborsClassifier(n_neighbors=5), LogisticRegression(), GaussianNB(), SVC()]
```